How to keep the order of a list of strings after a search?
Basically what I'm trying to do is:

Open and read a CSV file which is "names", "passwords" (Passwords
are HASH-SHA256 codes)

get the HASH code of every number in the range of "0000" to "10000".

and compare the hash code of every single number in a given range with the passwords in the CSV file

if the HASH code of for example number 2345 was equal to any of
given passwords in the CSV file, print the number.


Here is my code which does exactly what I want:
pw_dictionary = {}
data = []

with open("passwords.csv") as myfile:
    text = csv.reader(myfile)
    for i in text:
        data.append(i)

print("\n", data, "\n")

for n in range (10000):
    myhash = hashlib.sha256(str(n).zfill(4).encode()).hexdigest()
    pw_dictionary[str(n).zfill(4).encode()] = myhash
    for L in range(len(data)):
        if data[L][1] == pw_dictionary[str(n).zfill(4).encode()]:
            print(f'found u {data[L][0]}! pw: "{str(n)}"')


Output is:
 [['Zoro', 'f478525457dcd5ec6223e52bd3df32d1edb600275e18d6435cdeb3ef2294e8de'], ['Luffy', '297219e7de424bb52c040e7a2cbbd9024f7af18e283894fe59ca6abc0313c3c4'], ['Buggy', '6621ead3c9ec19dfbd65ca799cc387320c1f22ac0c6b3beaae9de7ef190668c4'], ['Shanks', '26d72e99775e03d2501416c6f402c265e628b7d02eee17a7671563c32e0cd9a3']] 

found u Zoro! pw: "1279"
found u Buggy! pw: "3941"
found u Shanks! pw: "8125"
found u Luffy! pw: "9723"


Problem is:
After I compare the given passwords with every number in that range(0000-10000), it messes up the order of the list. I want the output to be exactly in the same order as the "data" list. (Zoro>Luffy>Buggy>Shanks)
Instead, it sorts them based on the value of actual Numbers.
So how do I achieve that?

Change the order of loops?.... First for L in range(len(data)): and then for n in range (10000):

You should create the mapping of hash to PIN code only once, and then just do dictionary lookups. I've inlined data as a list-of-tuples, but the same thing applies for data read from a file.
import hashlib

data = [
    ("Zoro", "f478525457dcd5ec6223e52bd3df32d1edb600275e18d6435cdeb3ef2294e8de"),
    ("Shanks", "26d72e99775e03d2501416c6f402c265e628b7d02eee17a7671563c32e0cd9a3"),
    ("Luffy", "297219e7de424bb52c040e7a2cbbd9024f7af18e283894fe59ca6abc0313c3c4"),
    ("Ein", "4353ead3c9averysecretdoggocodewoofwoofac0c6b3beaae9de7ef190668c4"),
    ("Buggy", "6621ead3c9ec19dfbd65ca799cc387320c1f22ac0c6b3beaae9de7ef190668c4"),
]

hash_to_pin = {
    hashlib.sha256(str(n).zfill(4).encode()).hexdigest(): str(n).zfill(4)
    for n in range(10000)
}

for person, pin_hash in data:
    pin = hash_to_pin.get(pin_hash)
    if pin:
        print(f'found u {person}! pw: "{pin}"')
    else:
        print(f"no luck for {person}")

This prints out
found u Zoro! pw: "1279"
found u Shanks! pw: "8125"
found u Luffy! pw: "9723"
no luck for Ein
found u Buggy! pw: "3941"

– Ein's secret doggo code is much too secret for us.

can you please explain how that "for n in range(10000)" loop in the "hash_to_pin" line works? im not familiar with that syntax

@HaoShoku See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries about dict comprehensions.

I would first use a dictionary to speed up the search and the key is to store the passwords you successfully found, then sorting them accordingly to their place in your original dataset and then printing.
import csv
import hashlib

pw_dictionary = {}
data = {}

with open("passwords.csv") as myfile:
    text = csv.reader(myfile)
    for row in text:
        name, pw = row
        data[pw] = name


correspondences = []
for n in range (10000):
    input_password = str(n).zfill(4).encode()
    myhash = hashlib.sha256(input_password).hexdigest()
    if myhash in data:
        correspondences.append((myhash, n))

correspondences.sort(key=lambda x:list(data.keys()).index(x[0]))

for pw_hash,n in correspondences:
    print(f'found u {data[pw_hash]}! pw: "{str(n)}"')

This code outputs :
found u Zoro! pw: "1279"
found u Luffy! pw: "9723"
found u Buggy! pw: "3941"
found u Shanks! pw: "8125"

And with this code you can replace the input part by anything you want. You do the ordering afterward.
